# Execute an action on save in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: events, visual-studio-2012, envdte

In Visual Studio 2012, I found it is possible to use DocumentSaved events from DocumentEventsClass.
So I have written the following code in PowerShell.

```
$DTE.Events.DocumentEvents($DTE.ActiveDocument)
```

However, the COMObject returned is incorrect, (000... GUID). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute an action on Save, we found that the easy solution was to set a custom tool on the file. The same way RESX files work.

Basically, we added

```
MSBuild:CustomTarget
```

And this target will be called every time you save.

Comment: Where did you add this CustomTarget? In the .csproj file?
What do you mean by "set a custom tool on the file"?
Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I got it! Click a file, properties, Custom Tool. :-)